# Remove .php extension from my symfony project

Tags: php, symfony1

I have created two applications in my symfony project, but my second application i can only access using .php extension.

example http://192.168.1.3:9000/backend.php

I want to remove the .php extension from the backend project, is possible?

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to remove the extension from the file on the server [backend file on server]? or the url [http://192.168.1.3:9000/backend]?
Both can be done via htaccesss

Comment: yesss i need to access http://192.168.1.3:9000/backend, i tried in httaccess but Oops! Page Not Found error

Comment: `RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteRule backend$ backend.php [L]`

Make sure to have mod_rewrite

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but it is not worked same error, plz have a look to my .htaccess.                                                 
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  
  #RewriteBase /

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule backend$ backend.php [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 2):

You can rename your `backend.php` file to just `backend` without extension, then use following in your `.htaccess` config:

```
<Files backend>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

(One could also use `DefaultType` to make that possible for all php scripts, but this would cause extra work with unsetting it again in subfolders for security reasons.)

Comment: I do the same think u specified: but not worked.                         Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
<Files backend>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
.................. and renamed backend.php to backend

Comment: Hmm, no idea. Works for me. You could try `<FilesMatch ^backend$> ... </FilesMatch>` instead, but that's pretty much the same. -- If you had an additional RewriteRule in there, that might conflict. Use only either one approach! Not all at once.

Comment: I removed RewriteRule, now it works, but i cant get my images,stayles in that page? do u know what is the issue

Comment: Iam so thankfull for your help, so sorry for the delay for upvote acceptance , actually i forgot it.I removed all other re-write rules and added the re-write rules specified by you, now my backend page come, but i cant access my images,css and js on that page

Comment: Still hard to tell. But I would suggest adding a `<base href="/backend.php">` in the template for that script. That will keep relative resources paths (img,css) working. Albeit I'm not sure if the basename should really affect that. -- Otherwise: invoke one of the img/css urls directly and look for errors there.